# Binding on `statement` not supported in Eloquent 5.1?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm new to Laravel and trying to do a string query in Eloquent. I was trying to use `DB::statement`, but I kept getting errors about placeholders in the query string. It seems I either don't have the syntax right, or bindings are unimplemented or unsupported?

The reason I want to use `statement` is because I'm doing an `INSERT... SELECT`, which I haven't been able to find any documentation about in Eloquent.

Here's my code:

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.5.2 (PHP 5.6.13-0+deb8u1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> echo \DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE :db', [':db'=>'test']);
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 (SQL: CREATE DATABASE :db)'
>>> \DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE ?', ['test']);
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 (SQL: CREATE DATABASE test)'
```

These are the two syntax forms (`?` and `:string`) from PDO. Other methods in `DB` such as `select` and `insert` support this, according to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#running-queries).

The relevant parts of these errors are `near '?' at line 1 (SQL: CREATE DATABASE :db)` and `near '?' at line 1 (SQL: CREATE DATABASE test)`. MySQL thinks there is an unbound `?` in the query string. I didn't even use that syntax in the first query. I'm concluding from that that the `bind()` method did not correctly bind my placeholders.

[This question on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/l5-bindings-is-not-working-with-dbstatement) is asking about the syntax, but there is no accepted answer.

**Edit** One answer says that `statement()` doesn't support `CREATE`. I tried some queries out with `SELECT`, and got the same results, with both placeholders:

```
>>> \DB::statement('SELECT 1 WHERE \'a\' = ?', array('a'));
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 'a' = ?' at line 1 (SQL: SELECT 1 WHERE 'a' = a)'
>>> \DB::statement('SELECT 1 WHERE \'a\' = :letter', array(':letter'=>'a'));
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 'a' = ?' at line 1 (SQL: SELECT 1 WHERE 'a' = :letter)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can use `create` and `drop` query in `DB::statement()`, but **named bindings** is not used in that way.

Here are some queries that will success.

`drop` and `create` do not accept bindings.

```
>>> \Db::statement('create database test')
=> true
>>> \Db::statement('drop database test')                                                                                                                                              
=> true
```

Do not use backslash and single quotes in the statement

```
>>> \Db::statement('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', ['1', 'John'])
=> true
```

`DB::statement()` only return `ture` when success, so if you want to see `select` results, you should use `DB::select()`

```
>>> \Db::statement('select * from users')
=> true
>>> \Db::select('select * from users')                                                                                                                                                
=> [
     {#770
       +"id": 1,
       +"name": "John",
     },
   ]
```

Remove leading `:` in the second argument.

```
>>> \Db::statement('update users set name = :name where id = :id', ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John'])
=> true
```

You will get affect rows if you use `DB::update` and `DB::delete`

```
>>> \Db::delete('delete from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1])
=> 1
```

Comment: I tried again using `SELECT`, but that gave the same error. See my edited question towards the bottom. What query types does `statement()` support?

Answer (score 3):

The errors you receive are only indirectly related with Laravels DB::statement() function. They all fail within that method at the line

```
return $me->getPdo()->prepare($query)->execute($bindings);
```

within the file vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php

Responsible for that failure is the resulting call to [PDO::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php)

The Docuemenation says:

> Parameter markers can represent a complete data literal only. Neither part of literal, nor keyword, nor identifier, nor whatever arbitrary query part can be bound using parameters. For example, you cannot bind multiple values to a single parameter in the IN() clause of an SQL statement.

Also have a look at the user contributed notes at the above php.net documentation. Additionally have a look at [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

Your create examples are not supported by PDO.

The reason your SELECT examples fail is simply due to an invalid syntax.

```
\DB::statement('SELECT 1 WHERE \'a\' = ?', array('a'))
```

You are simply missing the FROM clause. This example works perfeclty well at my test computer:

```
$ret = \DB::statement('SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?', ["gregor"]);
```

But

```
$ret = \DB::statement('SELECT 1 WHERE `username` = ?', ["testname"]);
```

Generates the exact error, you receive.

Also note, that \DB::statement does not return any ressources. It just indicates by returning true or false, whether the query suceeded.

Your option is to use DB::raw() within your insert() statement, if you want to use INSERT...SELECT. Some googling will help you, to find the proper solution. Maybe as Starting Points: [Raw Queries in Laravel](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries), or [How to use raw queries in Laravel](http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/09/use-raw-mysql-queries-laravel/)

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is passing the table name through binding.

```
DB::statement('select * from ?',['users'])
```

which according to [this post](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304), it's not possible.

of course if you want to sanitize the data you can use an array of short codes like so:

```
$tables = ['users','test','another'];
```

and the query would look something like:

```
$code = 0;
DB::statement("select * from $tables[$code] where a=?",[2]);
DB::statement("create table $tables[$code]");
```